# how to create a python socket listener deamon

Tags: python, network-programming, daemon

i would like to know how to create a deamon that listens for a post request. i found this code to create a deamon on this [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/) but i didn't know how to fill it. 
im sending commandes from an android phone to a php server over json that redirects it to python that can communicate over serial to an arduino. i would like to know if there is any better solutions, thanks for your help

here is the code of the daemon creation:

```
    ## {{{ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/ (r6)
"""Disk And Execution MONitor (Daemon)

Configurable daemon behaviors:

   1.) The current working directory set to the "/" directory.
   2.) The current file creation mode mask set to 0.
   3.) Close all open files (1024). 
   4.) Redirect standard I/O streams to "/dev/null".

A failed call to fork() now raises an exception.

References:
   1) Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment: W. Richard Stevens
   2) Unix Programming Frequently Asked Questions:
         http://www.erlenstar.demon.co.uk/unix/faq_toc.html
"""

__author__ = "Chad J. Schroeder"
__copyright__ = "Copyright (C) 2005 Chad J. Schroeder"

__revision__ = "$Id$"
__version__ = "0.2"

# Standard Python modules.
import os               # Miscellaneous OS interfaces.
import sys              # System-specific parameters and functions.

# Default daemon parameters.
# File mode creation mask of the daemon.
UMASK = 0

# Default working directory for the daemon.
WORKDIR = "/"

# Default maximum for the number of available file descriptors.
MAXFD = 1024

# The standard I/O file descriptors are redirected to /dev/null by default.
if (hasattr(os, "devnull")):
   REDIRECT_TO = os.devnull
else:
   REDIRECT_TO = "/dev/null"

def createDaemon():
   """Detach a process from the controlling terminal and run it in the
   background as a daemon.
   """

   try:
      # Fork a child process so the parent can exit.  This returns control to
      # the command-line or shell.  It also guarantees that the child will not
      # be a process group leader, since the child receives a new process ID
      # and inherits the parent's process group ID.  This step is required
      # to insure that the next call to os.setsid is successful.
      pid = os.fork()
   except OSError, e:
      raise Exception, "%s [%d]" % (e.strerror, e.errno)

   if (pid == 0):   # The first child.
      # To become the session leader of this new session and the process group
      # leader of the new process group, we call os.setsid().  The process is
      # also guaranteed not to have a controlling terminal.
      os.setsid()

      # Is ignoring SIGHUP necessary?
      #
      # It's often suggested that the SIGHUP signal should be ignored before
      # the second fork to avoid premature termination of the process.  The
      # reason is that when the first child terminates, all processes, e.g.
      # the second child, in the orphaned group will be sent a SIGHUP.
      #
      # "However, as part of the session management system, there are exactly
      # two cases where SIGHUP is sent on the death of a process:
      #
      #   1) When the process that dies is the session leader of a session that
      #      is attached to a terminal device, SIGHUP is sent to all processes
      #      in the foreground process group of that terminal device.
      #   2) When the death of a process causes a process group to become
      #      orphaned, and one or more processes in the orphaned group are
      #      stopped, then SIGHUP and SIGCONT are sent to all members of the
      #      orphaned group." [2]
      #
      # The first case can be ignored since the child is guaranteed not to have
      # a controlling terminal.  The second case isn't so easy to dismiss.
      # The process group is orphaned when the first child terminates and
      # POSIX.1 requires that every STOPPED process in an orphaned process
      # group be sent a SIGHUP signal followed by a SIGCONT signal.  Since the
      # second child is not STOPPED though, we can safely forego ignoring the
      # SIGHUP signal.  In any case, there are no ill-effects if it is ignored.
      #
      # import signal           # Set handlers for asynchronous events.
      # signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIG_IGN)

      try:
         # Fork a second child and exit immediately to prevent zombies.  This
         # causes the second child process to be orphaned, making the init
         # process responsible for its cleanup.  And, since the first child is
         # a session leader without a controlling terminal, it's possible for
         # it to acquire one by opening a terminal in the future (System V-
         # based systems).  This second fork guarantees that the child is no
         # longer a session leader, preventing the daemon from ever acquiring
         # a controlling terminal.
         pid = os.fork()    # Fork a second child.
      except OSError, e:
         raise Exception, "%s [%d]" % (e.strerror, e.errno)

      if (pid == 0):    # The second child.
         # Since the current working directory may be a mounted filesystem, we
         # avoid the issue of not being able to unmount the filesystem at
         # shutdown time by changing it to the root directory.
         os.chdir(WORKDIR)
         # We probably don't want the file mode creation mask inherited from
         # the parent, so we give the child complete control over permissions.
         os.umask(UMASK)
      else:
         # exit() or _exit()?  See below.
         os._exit(0)    # Exit parent (the first child) of the second child.
   else:
      # exit() or _exit()?
      # _exit is like exit(), but it doesn't call any functions registered
      # with atexit (and on_exit) or any registered signal handlers.  It also
      # closes any open file descriptors.  Using exit() may cause all stdio
      # streams to be flushed twice and any temporary files may be unexpectedly
      # removed.  It's therefore recommended that child branches of a fork()
      # and the parent branch(es) of a daemon use _exit().
      os._exit(0)   # Exit parent of the first child.

   # Close all open file descriptors.  This prevents the child from keeping
   # open any file descriptors inherited from the parent.  There is a variety
   # of methods to accomplish this task.  Three are listed below.
   #
   # Try the system configuration variable, SC_OPEN_MAX, to obtain the maximum
   # number of open file descriptors to close.  If it doesn't exists, use
   # the default value (configurable).
   #
   # try:
   #    maxfd = os.sysconf("SC_OPEN_MAX")
   # except (AttributeError, ValueError):
   #    maxfd = MAXFD
   #
   # OR
   #
   # if (os.sysconf_names.has_key("SC_OPEN_MAX")):
   #    maxfd = os.sysconf("SC_OPEN_MAX")
   # else:
   #    maxfd = MAXFD
   #
   # OR
   #
   # Use the getrlimit method to retrieve the maximum file descriptor number
   # that can be opened by this process.  If there is not limit on the
   # resource, use the default value.
   #
   import resource      # Resource usage information.
   maxfd = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)[1]
   if (maxfd == resource.RLIM_INFINITY):
      maxfd = MAXFD

   # Iterate through and close all file descriptors.
   for fd in range(0, maxfd):
      try:
         os.close(fd)
      except OSError:   # ERROR, fd wasn't open to begin with (ignored)
         pass

   # Redirect the standard I/O file descriptors to the specified file.  Since
   # the daemon has no controlling terminal, most daemons redirect stdin,
   # stdout, and stderr to /dev/null.  This is done to prevent side-effects
   # from reads and writes to the standard I/O file descriptors.

   # This call to open is guaranteed to return the lowest file descriptor,
   # which will be 0 (stdin), since it was closed above.
   os.open(REDIRECT_TO, os.O_RDWR)  # standard input (0)

   # Duplicate standard input to standard output and standard error.
   os.dup2(0, 1)            # standard output (1)
   os.dup2(0, 2)            # standard error (2)

   return(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":

   retCode = createDaemon()

   # The code, as is, will create a new file in the root directory, when
   # executed with superuser privileges.  The file will contain the following
   # daemon related process parameters: return code, process ID, parent
   # process group ID, session ID, user ID, effective user ID, real group ID,
   # and the effective group ID.  Notice the relationship between the daemon's 
   # process ID, process group ID, and its parent's process ID.

   procParams = """
   return code = %s
   process ID = %s
   parent process ID = %s
   process group ID = %s
   session ID = %s
   user ID = %s
   effective user ID = %s
   real group ID = %s
   effective group ID = %s
   """ % (retCode, os.getpid(), os.getppid(), os.getpgrp(), os.getsid(0),
   os.getuid(), os.geteuid(), os.getgid(), os.getegid())

   open("createDaemon.log", "w").write(procParams + "\n")

   sys.exit(retCode)
## end of http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/ }}}
```

Comment: To create UNIX daemon I usually use this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

Comment: @DenisNikanorov: Seconded, and strongly recommended. `python-daemon` is the reference implementation of [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143).

Comment: Why do you need all these separate parts? Why can't you just have a Python server instead of a PHP server?

Comment: i use json between the android and the server

Comment: You can handle JSON in Python just as easily as in PHP. And same with talking to a database. (Alternatively, if you prefer PHP to Python, why not just do the Arduino stuff in PHP?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have to write a daemon, you definitely want to use [`python-daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/), as it's the reference implementation of [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143). There are a ton of little things you have to get right.

If you have to write a server, and have never done it, and don't need to handle more than 100 or so simultaneous connections, and don't need to share data between different clients, `threading` is by far the easiest solution.

An echo server daemon (which runs forever until you `signal` it, and doesn't attempt graceful shutdown) looks like this:

```
import socket
import threading
import daemon

def handle_client(sock):
    with sock.makefile() as f:
        sock.close()
        for line in f:
            f.writeline(line)

def serve_forever():
    server = socket.socket()
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(('0.0.0.0', 12345))
    server.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, address = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=[conn])
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    serve_forever()
```

Just put your real code inside that `handle_client` loop. This opens a [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example) listening on port `12345`.

---

But really, even this is more complicated than you need. An [`inetd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) service is a lot simpler:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

And to register it as a server on port 12345, just add one line to `/etc/inetd.conf`:

```
12345 stream tcp nowait nobody /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/myscript.py
```

And that's it.

Of course a modern *nix system is almost certainly not using old-school `inetd`, but rather `xinetd`, `systemd`, `launchd`, or some other replacement, so the configuration will be a little different. Read the appropriate docs for your system. But still, a lot simpler than writing a socket server daemon.

---

Alternatively… why do you need to write a PHP server to forward to a Python server? There are a few potential answers to that, but if you don't have one, you don't need to do this. Just use a Python service/CGI/whatever instead of a PHP one, and let the web server handle all the networking, daemonizing, management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your python code try to implement a server. Check this [post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/380019/simple-socket-server-in-python) and Create a Client from your PHP to connect to that Python Server.

See this [post](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) and when the PHP Client is connected to Python Server with relevant information initiate the communication to Arduino using Serial.

This [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/arduino-google-voice-activated-servo.html) showcases something similar but uses a Java Server which communicates to Arduino using Serial and a Python Client which connects to Java Server.